# DB2 Z/OS PYTHON connection

Tags: python, db2-zos

i am trying to do my first connection to DB2 Z/OS from Python from windows 64 bit. I have downloaded & successfully install python 2.7.9. according to the doc I also need ibm_db eggs and which is supposed to be installed from C:\Python27\Scripts. I do see easy_install-2.7 but when i click it , nothing gets installed as ibm_db under C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages. when i click on the easy install , it says that “no url – filename or requirement".

can you please tell me what I am missing here.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/installing/index.html